# How to edit a regex to also accept unfinished inputs in the right format?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, ecmascript-6

I try to validate a Dutch postal-code with JavaScript. I have a working solution which accepts a complete postal-code:

```
var dutchRegex = /^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i
```

It accepts anything like ***1234ab*** or ***1234 ab*** which is what I want.

But how do I edit this regex to work while the user inputs the code?

- 1 -> true
- 12 -> true
- 12r -> **false**
- 1234 a -> true
- 1234 ab -> ture
- 1234 abc -> **false**

Comment: This smells of "implementation overkill" -- ask yourself, do you really need to add this complexity? Would this really add much value vs just validating that the *whole input* is correct, when the user has *finished typing*?

Comment: Don't validate on keypress/keydown/keyup. Validate onChange.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unless you listen for events properly and employ 2 regexes then that would let the user submit incomplete data.

Comment: @TomLord I need this for a search input. The user should be able to input his/her zip-code and instantly get suggestions like

Input: 123
Suggested: 1234 AB - Sometone; 1235 AC - Someothertown

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, my experience is that users have no idea and will try to jam in the same regex regardless of event listener

Comment: Slight modification to Wiktor's regex to account for making `12r` false: `^[1-9](?:[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{0,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/gEu935/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think your comments are quite useful and instrumental to the end result. I will credit you in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen your Javascript so I assume you're using some form of keydown/keypress/keyup event listeners to tell the user that their input does not match the expected format.

For that you can use this regex:

```
^[1-9](?:[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{0,2})?$
```

- `^[1-9]` - start string with a digit 1 through 9
- `(?:` - start non capturing group

  - `[0-9]{1,3}` - we can have 1 to 3 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{0,2}` - require 3 digits followed by the rule for the alpha part of the zip code
- `)` - close non capturing group
- `?` - non-capturing group is optional
- `$` - end string anchor

https://regex101.com/r/gEu935/1

---

Note: my answer is a slightly modified version of a regex provided in the post's comments by [wiktor-stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be

```
^[1-9](?!\d{0,2} ?[a-z])\d{0,3} ?[a-z]{0,2}$(?<!s[ads])
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9]` Match a digit 1-9
- `(?!\d{0,2} ?[a-z])` Negative lookahead assert not 0-2 digits followed by a char a-z to the right
- `\d{0,3} ?` Match 0-3 digits and optional space
- `[a-z]{0,2}` Match 0-2 chars a-z
- `$(?<!s[ads])` Assert the end of the string and assert that it does not end with `sa` `sd` or `ss`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0SQZd/1)

```js
const regex = /^[1-9](?!\d{0,2} ?[a-z])\d{0,3} ?[a-z]{0,2}$(?<!s[ads])/;
["1",
  "12",
  "123",
  "1234",
  "1234 ",
  "1234 a",
  "1234 ab",
  "123r",
  "12r",
  "1r",
  "r",
  "1234 sa",
  "1234 sd",
  "1234 ss",
  "1234 abc"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} ==> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```